# Unable to simulate a SystemC model in Modelsim

Tags: modelsim

I've created a systemc-xor gate in eclipse. It works fine with a SystemC testbench.

Eclipse offers the possibility to make a coupling with VHDL, so I can make a testbench in VHDL and then simulate it with modelsim. A .so file is generated in eclipse, which should be loaded by the VHDL file. But when I run

```
vsim -gui     work.xor_gate_if_tb -do xor_gate_if_tb.do
```

I get the following error

```
Error: (vsim-3193) Load of "./xor_gate_if.so" failed: DLL dependent library not found.
```

Looking for more information about this error I find the following

```
Dynamic loading of the specified file did not succeed. Verify that the
full path to the file is correct and that the file is marked as readable.

Also verify that the object file was compiled and linked on the same type 
of platform as the QuestaSim that is trying to load it.
```

The file is in the current path, and both the compiling and simulation process are made in windows.

I would appreciate any help to solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: I would ask Mentor (the people who make modelsim) about this question. See http://model.com/content/modelsim-support

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I opened a service request. The asked me to check the dependency tree of the file (with dependency walker, for example). I found some unresolved dependencies and also that my .so file corresponds to a x86 architecture, although my cpu is 64-bit. I'm working on that :).